# Cannot create a runtime error=Other("can't convert a memory import into an export: failed to insert a new memory section

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node

I was running my substrate-blockchain on dev mode. And it gave me this error.

[image]

Comment: `cargo clean` `cargo update` `cargo build --release` might help

Comment: Can you give any details about what you've changed and what version you are using? What version of polkadot does the substrate you're using correspond to (check the branches in `Cargo.toml`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to a different version of toml are present in the code. If the cargo tomls has version = "0.9.36" and some of the tomls have version ="0.9.41".That's why it is showing duplicate sections.